# How do I change the content of a file with javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I want to have a function that will overwrite the content of a file in the same directory, on the user's computer that has downloaded the software. The file is an hta file, not an HTML file, so there should be no security issues with the browser.

Comment: Welcome to SO!  You should review [ask] for tips on formatting your questions.  As this question is presented from its onset, it lacks critical context for anyone to provide you with meaningful guidance.  Is this for a Node app?  Or a website?  Is it running in a normal browser, or electron?  What specific problem are you encountering?  Can you include an [mcve]?  These are all important for the community to provide you answers that will be helpful to you.

Comment: What file?  Where is this file?

Answer (score 1):

If your JavaScript code runs on the browser (expect your file is on the server), its impossible to do it due the security reasons, else you can use `fs` module on Nodejs.

Comment: That depends on where the file is.

Comment: i agree with you @Brad

Comment: The code does not run on the browser. It is an HTML application.

Comment: i think the HTML app will runs on the browser, doesn't it?

Comment: @MomoSetti I don't think that hta files run on the browser. HTML files do though. They appear to be standalone.